# Trying to build project after upgrade Debian in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, debian

I'm trying to build my project (in Qt-Creator, Debian 8) in Debian 9.
I get error

> /usr/include/c++/6/cstdlib:75: error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory

```
// Need to ensure this finds the C library's <stdlib.h> not a libstdc++
// wrapper that might already be installed later in the include search path.
#define _GLIBCXX_INCLUDE_NEXT_C_HEADERS
#include_next <stdlib.h>
#undef _GLIBCXX_INCLUDE_NEXT_C_HEADERS
```

`apt-get install libstd*` didn't solve the problem.

Comment: did you install build-essential . if not then install and give a try
sudo apt-get install build-essential

Comment: I've just installed build-essential. Didn't help.

Comment: Try to reinstalls gcc. Reinstalling sometimes fixes problems.
sudo apt install --reinstall gcc-5.4

Comment: sudo apt install --reinstall gcc-6* didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I added `QMAKE_CFLAGS_ISYSTEM = -I` to the **.pro* file of the project in Qt creator and the error got away.